# I want to display a specific item from an array using Jquery .change(function... (JS, EJS, Mongoose, Express)

Tags: javascript, jquery, express, nodes, ejs

In my project am using js, ejs, mongoose, express

I want to display a specific item from an array using Jquery.

I have a select element and every time am changing this element i want to extract the option value of it, parse it as an integer "i", put it on another array and display the specific array[i] in my html document

More informations about my project: i have a list of items (those items are inputs from the browser) in the select element. Every item has its own price (which is also another input from the browser) and would like to match every item with its own price.

So for exampe select item[1] changes to price[1], select item[2] changes to price[2]

this is my code:
'''

```
<li class="list-group-item" id="price">
<% let array = kiteProduct.price.split(','); %> 
 €  
</li>

<select class="form-select" id="sizes" aria-label="Default select example">
   <option value="0" selected>Select Size</option>
   <% let i = 0; %> 
   <% for (let element of kiteProduct.size.split(',')) {%>
   <option value=<%= i %> >
   <%= element %>

   </option>
   <% i++ %> 
   <% } %>
</select>
```

'''
and my JQuery
'''

```
   <script type='text/javascript'>
                $('#sizes').change(function () {
                    
                    var $arr = "<%=array; %>";
                    var $id = parseInt($(this).val());
                    // let price = arr[id];
                    var i = 0;
                    for (let j of $arr){
                        if (i === $id){
                            var price = j;
                        }
                        i++;
                    }
                    $("#price").text(price);
                });
            </script>
```

'''
i have also tried
'''

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
                $('#sizes').change(function () {
                    
                    var $arr = "<%=kiteProduct.size.split(',') %>";
                    var $id = parseInt($(this).val());
                    let price = arr[id];
                    $("#price").text(price);
                });
```

'''

when am passing the id in to my price my function works perfect `$("#price").text($id);` but it displays my id (e.g. 0, 1...) when am passing my id in to my array as i mention in my code, My code display's random values (e.g. item[0] -> html text "1", item[1] -> html text "0"

and i have already include my scripts
'''

```
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
            <script src="ejs.min.js"></script>
```

'''

which i believe i only need ajax, all the others are unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy answer by changing the option value on
`<option value=<%= array[i] %> >`

if you found something else that i can use it on jQuery let me know and post your answers!